# ReactJs - uncheck checkbox from postalJs subscription

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I have a component I would like to uncheck from a postal.js subscription. Using my code below the checkbox is always checked.

I am storing the value in state and setting it in ComponentDidMount. Can anyone tell me how I can uncheck it once I receive the subscription:

**UPDATED:**

```
var SelectAll = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        checked:false
    };
},

handler: function(e) {

    var updatedContacts = [],
        contacts = this.props.data.contacts,
        topic = 'selectAll',
        checked = false,
        channel = 'contact';

    contactChannel.publish({
        channel: channel,
        topic: topic,
        data: {
            selectAll: this.state.checked
        }});

        this.setState({checked: event.target.value});


},

render: function() {

    return (
        <div className="contact-selector">
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked}
                onChange={this.handler} ref="checkAll" />
        </div>
    );
},

setUnChecked: function(){
    this.setState({ selected: false });
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    contactChannel.subscribe("deselectedContact", function(data) {
        self.setUnChecked();
    });
}

});

module.exports = SelectAll;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `checked` attribute to a form field in ReactJS, you set it as [**controlled**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html). This means, that simple pressing it by a user won't change it's state (or writing sth in case of text fields won't change the text). You need to set it yourself, for example in your `handler()` function.

P.S. The data flow inside of the component is imho a bit of a mess - according to what I've just wrote, you should use some `this.state.XXX` variable in the `checked={XXX}` attribute and, when ckbx's pressed, update it in the `handler()` function using `this.setState()'. This will trigger automatic rerendering of the component in the DOM (of course if the state changes).

EDIT

```html
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    
</div>

<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">void function() {
'use strict';

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            checked: false
        };
    },
    
    handle: function(e) {
    
        /*
        Do your processing here, you might even prevent the checkbox from changing state - actually that is the main purpose of Facebook implementing the controlled/uncontrolled elements thing - to have full control of the input.
        */
        var currentMinute = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000 / 60);

        //The checkbox can be changed only in odd minutes
        if(currentMinute % 2 == 1) {
            this.setState({checked: e.target.checked});
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handle} />;
    }
});
 
React.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));

}()</script>
```

Comment: Thankf rot he reply, I have updated my code above to use state. Can you please tell me if I'm on the right lines?

Comment: Better use `event.target.checked`, but you're on good tracks - it should work. In the response edit I also provide the _comprehensible_ code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe ?

```
setChecked: function(isChecked) {
  this.setState({
    selected: isChecked
  });
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  var self = this; // <--- storing the reference to "this" so that it can be later used inside nested functions
  contactChannel.subscribe("deselectedContact", function(data) {
      self.setChecked(false); // <--- "this" would not refer to the react component hence you have to use self 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my post, can you please tell me how I could check for the target.checked and state.selected? Currently Im trying to combine them to see if the checkbox needs checking? How would be best to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps()`, it is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare `this.props` and `nextProps` and perform state transitions using `this.setState()` in this method.